# Android set custom style to Paint

Tags: android, paint

I'm wondering actually one thing about `Paint` class in Android. I was looking the code of `FingerPaint` example in Android SDK Demos and I'm curious is there any way to set a custom style for `mPaint` which they are using there. I mean to create something like new brushes which user can use to draw something.

```
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
```

Or maybe it's not calling style, not really sure but I didn't find anything useful over the internet about this question, so that's why I'm asking it here.

I'll be really happy if someone can give me suggestions/advices and information if it's possible and how can I do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about the "styles" you want to achieve. The Canvas and Paint API is very powerful and you can get a lot of effects.

Comment: I want to be able to paint on canvas with different brushes...I mean I want to know if there is a way to create custom brushes and paint with them?

Comment: ok i think i have a hunch of what you mean. Try to formulate your question so that somebody who doesn't use or know photoshop etc understands it. Using paints you can draw lines, paths shapes and gradients, even bitmaps. You can use porter duff blending modes, blur masking and color filters. You see its best if you give an example of what you mean by brush :-)

Comment: By brush I mean a custom group of dots and maybe lines. Here you can see actually what I want to achieve  https://lh3.ggpht.com/t5TU7lUJmsZdWQlhmTzh-EpiEund3cjHqZfO2_qMbMCWDTaAh_vs2x46OedvNuP0G-o . As in SBM application you can choose different types of strokes which you can use to draw. I hope you understand me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible to achieve what you want by using [BitmapShaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html). So you need a small Bitmap which acts as a mask containing the small lines and dots which make up the Brush. Use Shader.TileMode.REPEAT or MIRROR. To change the color of the brush you apply [ColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) to the Paint with setColorFilter.